# Liquibase - fix wrong rollback statement

Tags: liquibase, rollback

My master changelog is like below,

```
    databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/001_table1.sql
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/002_table2.sql      
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/003_table3.sql        
  ...
  ...  
  - include:
      relativeToChangelogFile: true
      file: tables/020_table20.sql,
```

and table12's script is as below,

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset user:table12.create stripComments:false splitStatements:true
create table table12
(
    id             integer not null,
    mod_timestamp  timestamp without time zone not null default current_timestamp
);
--rollback drop table table12 cascade;

--changeset user:table12.table12_ix1 stripComments:false splitStatements:true
create index table12_ix1 on table12(mod_timestamp);
--rollback drop index table12A_ix1 ;
```

After all changesets get deployed and executed(table1 to table20), I picked up the wrong rollback statement, which should be

```
--rollback drop index table12_ix1 ;
```

My question is, what is the best way to fix this? I could check in another changeset that drops the index and recreate it along with the correct rollback statement as below,

```
--changeset user:table12.table12_ix1_recreate stripComments:false splitStatements:true
drop index table12_ix1;
create index table12_ix1 on table12(mod_timestamp);
--rollback drop index table12_ix1 ;
```

But, if I kick off the "liquibase rollback-to-date ..." for example, it still hits an error when it reaches to this line "--rollback drop index table12A_ix1".

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you have already deployed this changeset to some environment(s), I guess the only thing left is to edit the existing changeset and fix the incorrect roll ack statement. This is the last resort solution which comes with consequences - you will have to take the checksums generated for this changeset from `DATABASECHANGELOG` table from **all** those environments and add them all to `validCheckSum` changeset tag. You can also set `validCheckSum` to `ANY` but it's not recommended as it might bring issues with false positives in future. See [Changeset Checksums](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/changeset-checksums.html) for details.

If the only environment you deployed this is your local environment that could be dropped and recreated, then simply do it.

To avoid this issue in future, I highly recommend using [`update-testing-rollback`](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/update/update-testing-rollback.html.) command instead of `update`.