# Liquibase disable some properties of the scripts

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I have migrated the Database from **Oracle** to **Postgres**. In **Oracle**, we`ve used **tablespaces** in the liquibase scripts, but in my new **Postgres** Database I do not want to use these **tablespaces** anymore. Is the a proper way to apply these scripts over a new environment that does not have any tablespaces (ignore that property)?

I`m running liquibase during **Spring Boot** start-up phase.

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase changesets have a dedicated [`dbms`](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/home.html) attribute to distinct the changesets incompatible between the different DB management systems:

> Specifies which database type(s) a changeset is to be used for. See valid database type names on [Liquibase Database Tutorials](https://docs.liquibase.com/start/tutorials/home.html). Separate multiple databases with commas. Specify that a changeset is not applicable to a particular database type by prefixing with !. The keywords all and none are also available.

So, you would need to use `dbms="oracle"` for Oracle-specific changesets, and `dbms="postgresql"` for Postgres.

Comment: thanks for your proposal, but I cannot change the existing changeset files. Was hoping there could be a flag that allows to ignore tablespaces in general during the migration

Comment: Technically, you can. It's not recommended, of course, but it is [possible in exceptional cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78065779/16417367) to fix issues like yours.